# How to using jquery to get content html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
test test test
</body>
</html>
```

How to ideas get only string "test test test" in jquery ?

Comment: No offence, but you should read some jQuery documentation first or atleast try to search the answer before asking questions. If you just google "jQuery get html", the first result is the jQuery `.html()` method which is the one you need.

Answer (score 3):

`$('body').text()` or `$('body').html()`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var $bodyval = $('body').html();
alert($bodyval);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  alert($("body").html());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var bodyText = $('body').text();
```